# How do I remove tailing "None" from my print list result in Python

Tags: python

I am making use of set difference to output all the missing elements in a given list as shown in the code snippet bellow.

```
def missingNum(a, N):
    arr = range(1, N+1)
    res = list(set(arr)-set(a))
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if type(i) != None:
            print(res[i])

N2 = 10
a2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
print(missingNum(a2, N2))
```

When I print out my final result I get the expected output with a trailing None as bellow;

```
Your Output is:
9
3
None
```

How do I print out just the output without the trailing None ?

Comment: Your function is returning `None`, so don't `print()` it, just call the function: `missingNum(a2, N2)`.